# Rate and reviews in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to show the rate that gave to products and reviews to each product by coding in custom home pgage not plugin and i try it

```
echo '<br/>' . $product->average_rating;
```

but no response

I already use woocommerce plugin

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

this will solve this issue

```
$rating_count = $product->get_rating_count();
$average_rating = $product->get_average_rating();
echo wc_get_rating_html( $average_rating, $rating_count);
```